# How can I find packages already installed on my computer that have a chocolatey equivalent?

Tags: windows, chocolatey

I would like to replace as many packages on my computer with the corresponding chocolatey packages, so they can be upgrade automatically.

Is there a possibility to scan the installed Apps and point out which of them have a chocolatey equivalent?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's probably not what you want to hear.

You can do this with the [Package Synchronization](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/features/package-synchronization/) feature, but this feature requires a Chocolatey for Business license (C4B). [Automatic Synchronization](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/features/package-synchronization/automatic-sync) is a similarly named feature (all paid licenses have it), but this only removes packages for which the related software was uninstalled outside of Chocolatey.

---

With the free version, you will have to instead synchronize your package state manually.

> **Note**: I don't recommend doing this for packages you don't maintain on the community feed. The likelihood of getting malware is low, but I'd be more concerned with a poor search term causing the wrong package to get installed instead, or accidentally installing a less "official" package maintained by someone who is not as diligent with updates or has abandoned the package.
>
> However, this should be a perfectly safe procedure for packages you develop and maintain (and in reality you'll probably know all the package ids and versions anyways, so you'll skip straight to step 3). Doubly so if you are installing from a private feed you or your organization controls.

1. Query your installed programs from Windows. Take note of the version you have installed so you can install the correct version.
2. Do a package search for each one, recording the package ID for each one.

   - `choco list --order-by-popularity --version VERSION` should help you avoid less official or less maintained packages for the same software, and get you the correct package version. Top of the list is the most popular.
   - This is not perfect as some software really only gets installed by a single version of the package, but either self updates or pulls from a latest URL. In these cases the package version is not usually updated or accurate.
3. Install each software per package ID you have. Do this one command at a time so you can specify the correct version.

   - `choco install -n` skips running the installation PowerShell script so it effectively only "imports" the package for management without performing the install.